# How to render with low quality

Tags: python, rendering

How to change the quality of renders in python and save low quality render output?

Low quality, small size (not default size)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Quality rendering". The quality of the render could mean multiple things like render samples, render resolution, render bounces and individual settings for properties like shadow samples, SSR, SSS, etc. You need to mention which specific properties you need to change. Your question is very vague ATM.

Comment: thx for edit my english

Answer (score 1):

```py
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = './'
bpy.ops.render.render(animation = False) 
img = bpy.data.images[0]
img.save_render('wynik.jpg')
```